# Append two XMlDocument C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

My soap service receives a XML and i need to add soap enevelope to the xml before i send it to a HTTP service, i get a error at 
line             httpDocumet.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xml.DocumentElement);

how can i append soap headers to my xml?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDocument HelloWorld(XmlDocument xml)
    {

        XmlDocument httpDocumet = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement soapEnvelope = httpDocumet.CreateElement("soap", "Header", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        soapEnvelope.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        soapEnvelope.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        httpDocumet.AppendChild(soapEnvelope);
        XmlElement soapBody =httpDocumet.CreateElement("soap", "Body", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        httpDocumet.DocumentElement.AppendChild(soapBody);
        httpDocumet.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xml.DocumentElement);
```

ERRROR MSG

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Server was unable to process request.
>   ---> System.ArgumentException: The node to be inserted is from a
>   different document context.    at
>   System.Xml.XmlNode.AppendChild(XmlNode
>   newChild)    at
>   WebService1.Service1.HelloWorld(XmlDocument
>   xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first `ImportNode` and then `AppendChild`.

```
var root = httpDocument.ImportNode(xml.DocumentElement, true);
httpDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(root);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the header to the `xml` variable and return that?